How to use the gdal_edit tool from GDAL installed within Anaconda?
I intend to modify the color interpretation of raster bands using the gdal_edit tool(https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#gdal-edit), and I have found relevant commands online to accomplish this task.
gdal_edit -colorinterp_1 red -colorinterp_2 green -colorinterp_3 blue -colorinterp_4 alpha D:\QGIS_Project\abc_a.tif
command come from Setting band 4 of raster to alpha with GDAL?
During my search, I realized that gdal_edit is not an executable (.exe) like gdaladdo, but rather a Python script. Consequently, I couldn't execute it directly in the command line as demonstrated in examples. I located all gdal_edit.py files within the Python environment where GDAL is installed and attempted to run these .py files using the corresponding python.exe, yet without success.


I'm wondering, how is this tool supposed to be properly utilized?
my anaconda version:2.5.1;python 3.11
2024/6/14 question append
I followed user30184's method to create a new test environment in Anaconda and reinstalled GDAL, verifying that it was successfully installed. However, when I activate the environment and run the command python "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\gdaltest20240614\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py", I encounter the error shown in the following screenshot.

I'm unsure where exactly the issue lies; could it be that I've overlooked configuring some environmental variables or similar settings? Please note, I am using Anaconda on a Windows 10 system.

I am not sure how it is supposed to work, but the following procedure worked for me on Windows with Miniconda.
conda create --name gdaltest2
conda activate gdaltest2
conda install -c conda-forge gdal

Test what we have
gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.9.0, released 2024/05/07

Find where the gdal_edit.py script is, in my case
C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\gdaltest2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py

Try to do simple edit with that path
python "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\gdaltest2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_edit.py" -unsetstats test.tif

That did work for me and test.tif file was edited.
I can see that there are some files in the directory C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\gdaltest2\Scripts which I suppose should behave as helper scripts so that gdal_edit could be launched simply by typing gdal_edit.
gdal_edit-script.py
gdal_edit.exe
gdal_edit.py

But a test with gdal_edit fails. Good news is that user does not need to be in the Scripts directory but the command fails everywhere. I guess that it means that the path is set correctly.
gdal_edit
failed to create process.

The gdal_edit.py works also but it must be launched from the Scripts derectory. Notice that this gdal_edit.py is not the real script but some instruction script with these contents:
#!C:/Program Files/Miniconda3/envs/gdaltest2\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'GDAL==3.9.0','gdal_edit.py'
__requires__ = 'GDAL==3.9.0'
__import__('pkg_resources').run_script('GDAL==3.9.0', 'gdal_edit.py')

The script itself seems to import correctly what it should:
python "C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\gdaltest2\Scripts\gdal_edit.py"
C:\Program Files\Miniconda3\envs\gdaltest2\Scripts\gdal_edit.py:4: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('GDAL==3.9.0', 'gdal_edit.py')
Usage: gdal_edit [--help] [--help-general] [-ro] [-a_srs <srs_def>]
...


I followed your instructions and gave it a try, then appended the results to the question I posted. Could you please take a look?

I can't say what is the reason for your issue. I used Miniconda, version  conda 23.3.1, and I installed GDAL from conda-forge. Python version is 3.12.3.

What operating system are you using on your computer? I don't have a ready solution to use gdal_edit.py directly at the moment, but within the OSGeo4W environment, you can execute the command straightforwardly.
